# A thought experiment in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to show the number of times each distinct element in a column in a table in a SQL database appears, alongside the particular distinct element in a new output table. Is it possible in a single statement over ramming my head over it manually?

Comment: Show the table structure, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: what RDBMS are you using e.g. SQL Server, Oracle etc.

Comment: @ChrisProsser SQL Server

Comment: Some sample data and what results you're expecting *might* give us a clue about what you're actually talking about.

Comment: Think you require Group By clause?

Comment: @Phil Sandler - 

From the Northwind Database,

SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) AS OrdersFromCustomerID7 FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID=7;

This shows me the distinct count for one particular element, but how do I show this alongside the particular CustomerID, and extend it to all such elements?

Comment: @dean, yes, you're right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having actually tried, how about this:

```
SELECT tmp.Field, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] t WHERE t.DesiredField = tmp.Field) AS Count
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT DesiredField FROM [Table]
) tmp
```

This would first select all distinct values from [Table] and in the outer select, take the values and the number of times they appear in the column.

You could also try

```
SELECT Field, SUM(1) AS Count FROM Table
GROUP BY Field
```

This should "flatten" the table so that it only contains distinct values in `Field` and the number of rows where `Field` has the same value.

---

I just tried the second - it seems to work nicely.

---

Turns out I was wrong all the time. The second example and the following actually return the same results:

```
SELECT Field, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM Table
GROUP BY Field
```

Comment: yes, the second was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: and what does sum(1) do?

Comment: You can imagine it as follows: Imagine a table that contains two columns and as many rows as the original table. The first column named `Field` contains the same values as the original table (NOT distinct!), the second column contains the number `1`. Then for all the rows that contain the same value in the `Field` column, all these `1`s are summed up and only one row is left that contains the field value and the sum.

Comment: How is this any better than an obvious COUNT(*)? :)

Comment: @dean OK, I have to correct myself. It seems `COUNT(*)` yields the same result. I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest just to use COUNT(). You'll see varieties on what your count parameter, so here are the options.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT, data INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,NULL)

SELECT data
      ,COUNT(*) Count_star
      ,COUNT(id) Count_id
      ,COUNT(data) Count_data
      ,COUNT(1) Count_literal
  FROM @tbl
 GROUP BY data

data        Count_star  Count_id    Count_data  Count_literal
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------
NULL        1           1           0           1
1           2           2           2           2
2           1           1           1           1
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

You'll see the difference coming with the treatment of NULL if you COUNT a field that contains NULLs.